# Unable to add current city for facebook test users

Tags: facebook, facebook-test-users

I am working on a location based feature so created some facebook test account under the test app. I was trying to add the current city for all of my test users (manually) but facebook throws back the below error on entering the city:

> The content you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be
>   temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may have expired, or
>   you may not have permission to view this page.

Tried multiple times but nothing seems to be working. Please help!

Thanks in advance for your reply :)

Comment: I have the same problem did you find a solution?

Comment: Any solution you have find for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't show live places and cities for test users.

So the solution is to create a page for your city with your test account and add that page to your city on your profile. You can do same for your work or education.