# Set test user's "Current City" for app using Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have created an app on developers.facebook.com.

I would like to set the "Current City" for a few test users I have created.  But when I "log in as this test user", I cannot change the current city to anything except "Kolkata".  I know, this is a very strange error, and I have tried on multiple web browsers on both a Mac and a PC, and I get the same error.  If I type anything other than "Kolkata", either nothing happens or I get the error "This content is no longer available."  If I type a "k", the city "Kolkata" comes up as a suggestion, and it allows me to select the city "Kolkata".  I have successfully edited some other things on test users' profiles, but there are also many other fields I have not been able to edit.  I do not care about the other fields very much.

Is it possible to give a facebook test user a "Current City" other than Kolkata, and if so, how?

(If this isn't the right place to ask this question, I'd be happy to move it.)

Note: other people appear to have had similar problems:  [Unable to add current city for facebook test users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875927/unable-to-add-current-city-for-facebook-test-users)

Comment: The problem is likely due to the fact that cities are represented as pages, but test users can not interact with “real” pages.

Comment: @CBRoe Thanks, that sounds plausible.  Now I've created some "fake" pages with test users, but these pages still don't show up.  Any ideas?

Comment: Those pages are probably not recognized internally as representing a city.

Comment: @TheMe, are you still able to add "Kolkata"? My test user accounts won't even let me do that. No matter what I enter, it just says `The content you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may have expired, or you may not have permission to view this page.`

Comment: @JamesToomey I am no longer able to add Kolkata, and am getting the same error as you.

Comment: @Theme, I opened a bug report with Facebook on this. I'll let you know when they respond.

Comment: @Theme, the FB developer basically blew it off. He just said test accounts have limited capability and closed it. I'm pretty sure this is a bug because it used to work, as you experienced, but they don't seem to care much.

Comment: @JamesToomey Thanks for doing that.  Oh well, I guess.